# Firebase serve in docker container works for functions but not hosting

Tags: firebase, docker, local, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I've set up the following container Dockerfile:

```
FROM devillex/docker-firebase

ENV USER=app

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssl \
        libssl-dev \
        bash \
        less \
        vim \
        gnupg \
        curl \
        net-tools \
        apt-transport-https \
        ca-certificates; \
    CLOUD_SDK_REPO="cloud-sdk-$(grep VERSION_CODENAME /etc/os-release | cut -d '=' -f 2)" &&\
    echo "deb https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt $CLOUD_SDK_REPO main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list &&\
    curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -; \
    apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        google-cloud-sdk \
        google-cloud-sdk-cloud-build-local &&\
    gcloud config set project request-a-dance

RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" --shell /bin/bash $USER &&\
    mkdir /home/app/src &&\
    npm install firebase-tools mocha standard

USER app
WORKDIR /home/app/src

EXPOSE 5000 5001 9005
```

With an accompanying docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  firebase:
    image: firebase:local
    hostname: "firebase-local"
    build:
      context: ../..
      dockerfile: docker/local/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ~/.config:/home/app/.config
      - ~/.bash_aliases:/home/app/.bash_aliases:ro
      - ~/.bashrc:/home/app/.bashrc:ro
      - ../../src:/home/app/src/
    ports:
        - 5000:5080
        - 5001:5001
        - 9005:9005
    tty: true
```

I ran through the `firebase init` process inside my container image and now I have the following file structure inside the `src` directory:

```
|- .firebase
|- .firebaserc
|- .gitignore
|- firebase-debug.log
|- firebase.json
|- firestore.indexes.json
|- firestore.rules
|- functions
  |- index.js
  |- node_modules
  |- package.json
  |- package-lock.json
|- public
  |- index.html
```

I ran `firebase deploy` and when I visited the url for my hosted app, the browser returned the contents of `public/index.html`

However when I now run `firebase serve -o 0.0.0.0` inside the running docker container, requests to `0.0.0.0:5001` return:

```
// 20190920055855
// http://0.0.0.0:5001/

{
  "status": "alive"
}
```

And here is the problem: requests to `0.0.0.0:5000` return to the browser:

```
This page isn’t working 
0.0.0.0 didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

I've read through other answers on stackoverlfow such as [firebase serve in docker container not visible to host os](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42764151/20178) but it seems like this should be an all or nothing deal, both hosting and functions should fail or work but not functions work while hosting fails.

I'm fairly certain that something is off within my `firebase.json` `hosting` config, but given that it works when deployed I'm not sure how that would be.

Comment: Have you spot the line `ports: - 5000:5080`? Maybe should `- 5000:5000` not 5080?

Comment: @zzeroo Your careful reading took me a number of days and creating a simple express server to finally spot. Please repost as an answer and the bounty is all yours. Doh!

Comment: What is the issue from this boundary you are expecting to be answered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you spot the line

```
ports:
    - 5000:5080
```

Maybe should `- 5000:5000` not **5080**?